# Web application frameworks without needing to write HTML/UI

Tags: java, html, user-interface, web

Any there web application frameworks without needing to write HTML/UI?

I want to develop a web application from end to end but I am not familiar with HTML/UI, so looking for a Java based framework or tool which generates UI/HTML code automatically without actually writing  HTML code (like Eclipse's UI designer plugin).

So can anybody suggest if there are there any tools/plugins to do that?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to learn HTML if you're writing a web application.  Otherwise you're going to have a *really* difficult time supporting that application.

Comment: @David  I was just trying to think how to phrase that politely.  Thanks for saving me the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be a single correct answer to this question and I agree with the initial comments. However, three technologies that came to mind instantly:

- [Google Web Toolkit](http://www.gwtproject.org/), GWT
- [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com) (based on GWT)
- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch), you'd have to be familiar with JavaScript though

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the tools such as WYSIWYG (i.e. What You See IS What You Get).

Where without knowledge of ui you can still design ui.